# Make Firefox use the favicon as window icon under Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, unix, favicon

Is there a Firefox feature, setting, or add-on that arranges it so that the favicon of the currently open web page becomes the icon of the browser window in Linux/X11?  In particular, it ought to show up in the window manager's task bar.  Konqueror does that, and I find it very useful, considering that many "applications" are nowadays web pages.

Comment: Not that I need that much this feature, but I'm now interested/curious about it! Nice question!

Comment: Nice feature idea.

Comment: still looking for such add-on..

Comment: worth a bounty...

Comment: i don't use KDE or Konqueror, but i'd wonder whether the behavior you describe works properly under GNOME vs under KDE.  my feeling is that this is more a job for the window manager / taskbar than the application.  just a guess, though, i'm not an expert in the interiors of linux desktop environments.

Comment: Bump bump bump.

Comment: @quack quixote: Yes, also works when using Konqueror in GNOME or LXDE.

Answer (score 3):

Not a ready answer yet, but might lead in the right direction:

One could use [xseticon](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/) as pointed out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179174/change-icon-for-an-application-form-command-line).

Still open:

- automatically get the faviocon of actual page
- store it somewhere
- use `wmctrl` to find out the id of the firefox-window
- call `xseticon`

Answer (score 2):

One option is using [Mozilla Prism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665) firefox extension which allows you to run a webpage in its own dedicated window. It will use the favicon for the browser window icon.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and related in spirit to my question, but it doesn't really do what I want.  I couldn't actually get it to work either.

Comment: There is a standalone version of Prism as well (http://prism.mozilla.com/), but that is diverging even further from your original request.  Too bad the plugin didn't work, still in the "labs" I guess...